# Delete Section based on user input

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to delete an entire section/paragraph of a word doc based on user input.

The document has sections like "1.1" and "1.1.1" and "1.2"  The user would enter "1.1.1" and macro would delete that section. Is it possible to have the macro search for "1.1.1" and delete everything starting with 1.1.1 up to, but not including 1.2?

I started with this, but need to create a start and end point to delete.

```
Sub DeleteParagraphContainingString()

Dim search As String
search = "1.1.1"

Dim para As Paragraph
For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

    Dim txt As String
    txt = para.Range.Text

    If InStr(LCase(txt), search) Then
        para.Range.Delete
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Find` functionality of Word, then select the whole section and delete it. I give you a few code snippets that you can weave together, apply checks, etcetera:

```
ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select               ' go to beginning of document

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .text = yourFindString
    .Replacement.text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

While (Selection.Find.Execute)
    Selection.Bookmarks("\HeadingLevel").Select         ' select whole Section
    title = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.text          ' get Section Title (text of first paragraph)
    Selection.Delete
Wend
```

I hope this helps.